# Bitbucket/Django - No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing

Tags: python, django, bitbucket

I'm trying to create a new `Django` with `virtual environment` and connect it with **BitBucket** repository but I have some problems.

I will write here the whole process, maybe you'll figure out where am I wrong and it may be helpful fort other people.

I'm using Windows 8.1

1. `cd` to folder where my project will be

   `cd C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects`
2. Create my project folder

   `C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects>mkdir sfl_project`
3. `cd sfl_project`
4. Create **Virtual Environment**

   `C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>virtualenv venv`
5. Activate **Virtual Environment**

   `C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>venv\Scripts\activate`
6. Install **Django** in **Virtual Environment**

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>pip install django`
7. Start **Django** project

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>django-admin startproject sfl_project`
8. `C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>cd sfl_project`
9. Start **Django** app

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project\sfl_project>python manage.py startapp web`

   10. `cd..`
   11. Initialise **Git**

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>git init`

   12. Create a repository on the **BitBucket**
   13. Create **gitignore** file

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>echo venv/>> gitignore`

   14. And here is probably the problem, as far as I know, I should connect `sfl_repo` with local repo.

   `(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>git remote add origin https://profile@bitbucket.org/profile/sfl_repo.git` -> OK

   ```
   (venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>git push -u origin --all
   ```

**CMD SAYS:**

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

But I have files there, for example `app` called `web` and other files. Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try: git push --set-upstream origin master

And this is for the first time only, after that your command  should do.

Comment: git --set-upstream origin master does not work, --set-upstream origin master does not work neither. How should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added anything to your local repo; there is nothing to push.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have files there - (venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\Git_Projects\sfl_project>ls
gitignore  sfl_project  venv  What should I do?

Comment: Like I said, add them with `git add` and `git commit`.